# Pausing a custom iframe video with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I am embedding a video into a custom iframe, and I'm not using youtube, vimeo or any of those so I can't use their APIs. I am making an idle-timer for it, so when the user hasnt acted in X amount of time, it will bring up a `confirm` window asking if they want to keep watching or restart. However, while this window is up, I want the video to pause, which is proving surprisingly difficult. It also pretty much needs to be cross-domain as I will be serving the videos with an s3 bucket.
I have seen many threads saying this is basically not possible, but I find that hard to believe. Is it true?

Here's my code (the main part I need help with is pauseVideo() near the bottom):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HRMSC</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <iframe class="iframe" id="primaryVideo" src="amazon-s3-video-link.mp4"
             width="1000"
             height="562.5">
            <p> Your browser does not support iframes. </p>
       </iframe>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./IdleScript.js">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

`IdleScript.js :`

```
var idleTime = 0;
var clickIframe = window.setInterval(checkFocus, 100);
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 600); // 1 second
var i = 0;

function checkFocus() {
  if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById("primaryVideo")) {
    idleTime = 0;
    console.log("clicked "+(i++));
    $('#primaryVideo').blur();
   }
}

function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime = idleTime + 1;
  if (idleTime > 5) { // seconds
    console.log("restart?");
    if (this.resetInterstitial()){
      idleTime = 0;
      window.location.reload();
    }
    else{
      idleTime = 0;
      console.log("keep watching");
    }
  }
}

var pauseVideo = function ( element ) {
  // WHAT CAN I DO HERE?
  console.log("pause!");
  // WHAT CAN I DO HERE?
};

function resetInterstitial(){
  pauseVideo(primaryVideo);
  return confirm("You haven't tapped anything in a while. Do you want to keep watching or start from the beginning?");
}
```

Comment: iFrames are oldschool. :D.ont use them

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Why dont use a video tag?

Comment: This is just a wrapper for a custom video player I need to embed. From what I understand you need iframe to embed custom things like that. In other words, I won't just be passing a normal video once I get this working.

Comment: "This is just a wrapper for a custom video player I need to embed."  Then you'll need to use that custom video player's API to play or pause the video (and presumably the iframe src is for the custom player, not the video file itself as you've shown here?)  If you can tell us what player you're using we can maybe help; otherwise there's not much information anyone here can give you.

Comment: @DanielBeck Okay, sorry, I guess I'm not being clear enough. What I mean is that I have a web application which has a custom video player; I need to use an iframe so that I can run an instance of my web app in it. So there's a video player in it, but I don't see how I could access my API from a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<video>`-tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp
and use the build-in javascript functions https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp